# Remove <style> from head - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to remove this element from `<head>`

```
$('head').append('<style>#hide-menu-bg {border-bottom: solid 1px #361e1e;} #hide-menu-bg:after {border-bottom: solid 1px #703f3f;} </style>');
```

I tried this:

```
$("style.hmbg").remove();
```

But it only remove the class from `<style>` not whole element - `<style>`

Answer (score 4):

the style element does not have the class

```
$('head').append('<style class="hmbg">#hide-menu-bg {border-bottom: solid 1px #361e1e;} #hide-menu-bg:after {border-bottom: solid 1px #703f3f;} </style>');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zsJeV/)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have this?

```
$("style.hmbg").remove();
```

That will look for a style tag with the class `hmbg`.

- Make sure the javascript comes after the style tag.

Just have the code execute this:

```
$("style").remove();
```

If you have mire than one style tag, this would be a good use for the HTML5 `data-*` attribute.

Your code could reed like this:

```
$('head').append('<style data-test>#hide-menu-bg {border-bottom: solid 1px #361e1e;} #hide-menu-bg:after {border-bottom: solid 1px #703f3f;} </style>');
```

And then:

```
$("style[data-test]").remove();
```

Note: you could give the data attribute a value but for his we don't need to.